# Up or Down? What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

Up or down, down or up?
You may find me inside your cup.
Found or not, not or found,
I might be upon the ground.
Here or there, there or here,
You won't like me inside your ear.
Play or sit, sit or play,
What am I, do you say?

Comment: Responses may be a little slow today, but I'll get to them (unless this is solved in five minutes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could be

> water.

Up or down, down or up?

> Could be a reference to "drink up" vs "down a drink", or maybe upstream and downstream.

You may find me inside your cup.

> You might be drinking water from a cup.

Found or not, not or found,

> Perhaps a reference to water diviners that purport to be able to sense water in the ground.

I might be upon the ground.

> Puddles are certainly water on the ground.

Here or there, there or here,

> Could be in reference to the phrase "water, water everywhere [and not a drop to drink]".

You won't like me inside your ear.

> Nobody likes water in their ear.

Play or sit, sit or play,

> I'm not sure about this one. I would have expected "stand" and "babble", maybe.

What am I, do you say?

> You might be water.

Comment: Darn! I was literally about to post the same answer :)

Comment: Yep! I thought I gave a little too much away. I'll accept the answer when I can.

Comment: This only seems to explain every other line. @AggieKidd is there any significance to the "down or up", "found or not", etc. parts?

Comment: There is, but just clues as well. I'll definitely give a vote up to someone who gets those in as well.

Comment: +1 for excellent answer, but I don't personally enjoy the reasons to each line.

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure that the answer for this riddle is

> water